# How do i revert these batch commands that have been run?

Tags: windows, batch-file, tcp, windows-10

I heard from someone that these commands would increase performance in Windows 10 so i put them in a .bat file and ran them but they made it drastically worse and if anyone knows how to revert the changes i'd appreciate it a lot. Commands below.

Command 1

```
@echo off
@echo
bcdedit /deletevalue useplatformclock
@echo
bcdedit /set disabledynamictick yes
@echo
bcdedit /set useplatformtick yes
pause
```

Command 2

```
@echo off
@echo

REG ADD HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\ /v TcpAckFrequency /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

REG ADD HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\ /v TCPNoDelay /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

start explorer.exe

netsh int tcp set global rsc=disabled

netsh int tcp set global rss=disabled

netsh int tcp set global ecncapability=enabled

netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled

cd\
netsh int tcp show global
netsh int tcp set global chimney=enabled
netsh int tcp set heuristics disabled
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
netsh int tcp set global congestionprovider=ctcp

netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="Wi-Fi" static 1.1.1.1
netsh interface ipv4 add dns name="Wi-Fi" 1.0.0.1 index=2

@echo
@pause
```

Comment: Revert to what? Do you know the original settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should reset all values set from the script number 2:

```
reg delete HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\TCPNoDelay
reg delete HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\TcpAckFrequency
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
netsh winsock reset
```

Run as administrator.